# How do i extract values with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Hi am using beautiful soup to extract the euro to us value, this is what i got so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def Euro_spider():
    url = 'http://fx-rate.net/USD/'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
```

what should i do next?

Comment: I'm sorry to say you will get down voted for a question like this. In general you need to show what you have tried before posting a question. Consider Googling for beautiful soup tutorials.

Comment: i tried alot of things. But now i see that i neever put .get_text() before. Alecxe got it thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you need to locate the correct element containing the rate:

```
<a href="/USD/EUR/" class="1rate" title="Dollar to Euro">0.895</a>
```

You can locate it, for example, by `title`:

```
usd_to_euro = soup.find(title="Dollar to Euro").get_text()
print(usd_to_euro)  # prints 0.895
```